# copy_from_user not working for char*

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm a bit new to kernel programming so please excuse the question. Essentially, I want to send a string (char*) to the kernel module to print out. Pretty simple.

I have the following in a user level code:

```
char *text = "some text.";      
ioctl(fd,OUTPUT_TEST,text);
```

And there's inside the module:

```
char *text;
case OUTPUT_TEST:
    copy_from_user(text,(char *)arg,sizeof(char*);
```

However, text remains null. Shouldn't this be a pointer to the character string?

I'm even more confused because the following does work:

In user level:

```
typedef struct
{
   int size;
   char *text;
}Message;

  int fd = open ("/proc/ioctl_test", O_RDONLY);
  Message message;
  message.text = "This message was sent via OCTL.";
  message.size = strlen(message.text);

  ioctl(fd,OUTPUT_TEST,message);
```

And in kernel space:

> ```
> copy_from_user(&message,(Message *)arg,sizeof(Message));
> ```

This works perfectly. I'm really confused and would love any help you guys could offer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't mean to sound harsh but I think you need to learn C a bit before writing kernel modules :-)

copy_from_user does exactly what the name implies - it copies a buffer form user space provided buffer to kernel provided buffer. This means you need to provide a kernel allocated buffer for it, it does not allocate one for you!

Your char * text allocates a pointer to a buffer, but not a buffer. You need to do the buffer allocation yourself.

Note that in your second example the Message struct is defined as global or on stack (can't tell from your example) so the allocation occurs and it works.

Comment: Thanks! I did kind of think that I'd need to allocate a buffer, that's why the Message struct contains the size of the message. I'm still not sure I understand why when copying the struct (which is just an int and a pointer), it also copies over the text buffer.

Also, I'm confused why in the first copy_from_user, text is still null. No, it won't copy the buffer, but shouldn't the content (such as the user space pointer) be copied? I know that pointer wouldn't work, but I'm not sure why text remains null.

Comment: @kodai: Your `Message` example doesn't copy the text buffer at all - it just copies the (userspace) address of the text buffer.  This is buggy, because userspace pointers shouldn't *ever* be directly dereferenced by the kernel - it doesn't work on all architectures, and even where it does work it's insecure.

Comment: Also, don't forget you need to copy the entire string. ``copy_from_user(text,(char *)arg,sizeof(char*));`` only copies the size of a pointer. Should be something like ``copy_from_user(text,(char *)arg,strlen(arg));``, but I don't remember if kernel code implements ``strlen``.

Comment: by "allocating buffer in kernel", they mean doing `text[16]; copy_from_user(text, (void __user *)arg, 16);`. But it's strange copying the struct worked. Because the struct contained pointer (user-space), we need to copy the contents separately (do they call it deep-copy?).